# Не работает audio.get через VKApi на js

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, аудио

Итак, первым делом я сделал это:

```
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

После чего в `index.js` написал это:

```
VK.init({
   apiId: ********
   });

VK.Auth.login(function(response) {
   });

VK.api("audio.get", {uid:viewer_id,count:count}, function(data) {
   alert(data.response);
   var obj_respone = eval('('+ data.response +')');;
   for(var i=0; i<data.response.length; i++){
     document.getElementById('tracks').innerHTML+="<a href="+data.response[i].url+">"+data.response[i].artist +'-'+data.response[i].title+"</a><br />";
   }
   });
```

Затем в терминале написал `electron`.
Открывается дефолтное окно авторизации, авторизируюсь, и всё.
Ничего не работает. Очень прошу помочь.

Comment: Откуда вы берете переменные `viewer_id` и `count`? Зачем вы оборачиваете ответ от ВК в `eval()`? Зачем вы что-то вообще делаете с ответом ВК, если коллбек-функция возвращает объект, а не строку, содержащую JSON?

Comment: @terron а причем тут electron  в каком-то терминале вам не интересно?))

Comment: В консоли какие-нибудь ошибки есть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну, я подозреваю, что человек разрабатывает под [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) и имеет в виду его консоль.

Comment: @terron , я в этом случае просто сделал вот так: `        VK.api("audio.get", function(data) {
        alert(data.response);
        });
` и все равно нет результата

Answer (score 1):

1. При авторизации пользователя вы не запрашиваете [права доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions) к аудиозаписям.
2. У вас ошибка при конкатенации строки возле `href` - у атрибута не будет кавычек.
3. [`VK.Auth.login()`](https://vk.com/dev/openapi?f=3.1.%20VK.Auth.login) - асинхронный метод.
4. В цикле вы перебираете объект `response`, а надо перебирать объект `response.items`, который содержит в себе массив аудиозаписей.

Пример кода:

```
VK.init({
    apiId: 123456
});

VK.Auth.login(function (response) {
    VK.api('audio.get', {
        uid: viewer_id,
        count: count
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.error) {
            alert('VK API error #' + data.error.error_code + ': ' + data.error.error_msg);

            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < data.response.items.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('tracks').innerHTML += '<a href="' + data.response.items[i].url + '">' + data.response.items[i].artist + '-' + data.response.items[i].title + '</a><br>';
        }
    });
}, 8); // доступ к аудиозаписям
```

**UPD**

Похоже, что вы разрабатываете под Electron. Если это так, то Open API у вас работать не будет, потому что Open API предназначен для веб-сайтов с доменным именем. Вам надо использовать прямые запросы к API и создать во ВК приложение типа standalone.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
Open api access error {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"check domain settings"}

А так, спасибо за оптимизацию кода

Comment: @user228687, дополнил ответ. Смотрите под блоком с кодом.